# Create training samples for eCognition

Tags: ecognition

Most of the tutorial videos, they simply add those training samples. Looking at the attribute table they seems like, they in some specific format. Like all the training samples belonging to perticular class have one object id. However, if you create training samples using ArcGIS each polygon will have different object ID.

Comment: The question title and the contents are different. The title is about ecognition and the contents are talking about ArcGIS. Please make your question clearer and consistent.

Answer (score 1):

By interpreting the content of your question, I believe that you are interested to seek how training sample file (shapefile) is created for its onward use in eCognition for image classification. It is assumed that you are using ArcGIS to create your sample file.

in eCognition, there are various classifier algorithms to work with. As a preliminary step you will have to create a training file containing unique IDs (not object ID) assigned to each class in a **separate column** of a shapefile to train the classifier (e.g. SVM, Random Forest, KNN etc).

You should assign a unique ID to all samples corresponding to same landcover class you have identified from given image. For instance, a unique id of '1' may be assign to all samples from 'Forest' class and '2' may be assigned to all samples representing 'Water' marked from the image.

in eCognition, 'assign class by thematic layer' algorithm is applied by specifying the shapefile column containing unique IDs assigned to each class.

Thereafter, the 'Classifier' algorithm is employed to 'train' your samples for onward use in classification algorithm.

Comment: Thank you so much for understanding the content of my question. Can you please elobrate the method to generate those training samples. It will be very helpful.

Comment: After hours of strugling, I have found that the shape files created through QGIS are working in eCognition.

Comment: You can create the sample shapefile in ArcGIS as well.